# ipv6 over mesh on contiki

Tags: routes, ipv6, contiki

Working on the Contiki - Cooja Simulator, I am wondering how should I use mesh routing which is implemented on rime stack along with IPv6 based uIP stack. My main concern is to tunnel ipv6 packets over mesh under routing. So any help please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, as shown here: http://contiki.sourceforge.net/docs/2.6/a01725.html
There are three functions: to open, close and send.

The open requires a mesh_conn struct to fill with mesh_callbacks and channels.

mesh_callbacks requires three callback functions to use during receiving, sending and timeout.

and I guess close and send are pretty straightforward.

There is an example in the examples directory called example-mesh.c
http://contiki.sourceforge.net/docs/2.6/a00011.html

About UIP and IPV6, add `make UIP_CONF_IPV6=1` while building.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think that the rime stack is not compatible with IPv6, because when i activate IPv6 support the compiler reports 'multiple definition' of the functions rime_sniffer_add() and rime_sniffer_remove() which are located in rime.c as well as in sicslowpan.c.

Comment: you probably compiled it twice, once with `make UIP_CONF_IPV6=1` and once without, this should duplicate some functions/files

you should run `make clean` before the switch

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Contiki requires that you select either Rime or IP networking stacks at compile time, and the `mesh` routing functionality is Rime-specific.

For IPv6 routing, Contiki supports the RPL routing protocol.